# Printf and Scanf device driver function

Tags: linux-device-driver

In C program,there are printf and scanf functions which are actually functions connecting the program with output screen device and input keyboard device.
Is it right to look at printf and scanf functions as device driver functions?

Answer (score 1):

No, because they **don't** interact with devices at all. There are probably a good 5–6 layers of abstraction between printf/scanf and the actual device drivers.

Really *the whole point* of printf/scanf functions is that they use "standard I/O" – they only interact with abstract "file descriptors" provided by the OS. They actually don't even know whether a given file descriptor is reading from keyboard or a file or a TCP socket, because that's the job of the OS kernel.

(In fact, even in the "keyboard" case, the input file descriptor usually has nothing to do with actual keyboard devices but corresponds to another abstraction layer, the "tty" or "terminal device". And even that tty is virtualized – it could be a serial port, or an xterm window, or an SSH connection, or a telnet socket.)

As an example, if your program is running inside GNOME Terminal, you'll have:

physical keyboard device → kernel PS/2 device driver → /dev/input device abstraction (evdev) → the "libinput" event processing library → the X11 graphical environment (XInput2 events) → the GTK application toolkit → the VTE terminal emulator → kernel "pseudo-tty" (pty) device → 'stdin' file descriptor → C standard library FILE* abstraction → sscanf() function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you suggest any book that will help me understand the given example in more detail? In other words is it possible to tweak the given keyboard example to accommodate a finger print scanner using the sscanf () function

Comment: Great answer @user1686 (actually bad @$$).  I couldn't have written it better myself.  +1 even though you clearly don't need the points. :)  And Deepak, you should mark this as an answer as you won't get a clearer one.